# Items ImageButton drawable change upon click in ListView seems to change for 2 items at a time

Tags: android, android-listview, imagebutton

I know this question has been asked before and got an understanding roughly of whats happening but i cant seem to find a solution.

In my Custom List Adapter and inside `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {` ive setup a click function for the items ImageButton.

```
final ImageButton bookmark = (ImageButton)
convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookmarkthis);
        bookmark.setTag(position);
        bookmark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                bookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmarked);
                bookmark.setTag(R.drawable.ic_bookmarked);

}

});
```

The Imagebutton is a clear star and when Clicked it changes that same drawable to a yellow star. It works Ok.

Problem is when i click Item in Position 0 Star Icon to make yellow , it also changes for item 8 further down the list not in View Yet. if i click position 1 changes also for position 9 and so on.

I had a look around and researched the issue and even tried a holder for the Imagebutton but no go. Something is preventing the drawable change for the ImageButton to its correct Position only.

Thanks

**Solution** is to initially Set a flag item in the array for each Item. Then onClick set the flag to true just for that item. Then in the getView its just a case of an if statement to check the flag as the Items get Cycled.

```
//in array creation
items.setFlag("false");

//in getView as you set Text and what ever get the Flag state
String flag = m.getFlag();

 //check the flag state and take action in this case change the icon accordingly
 if (Objects.equals(flag, "true")) {
            bookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmarked);
            bookmark.setTag(R.drawable.ic_bookmarked);
        }

        else {
            bookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark);
        }


// and in the click function
           @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    bookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmarked);
                    m.setFlag("true");

    }
```

Comment: Please show your entire `getView` method.

Comment: @Buddy -- no problem, its quite long though because i'm checking the database if its bookmarked

Comment: It is probably because you are recycling the views and not  re-inflating it the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset your `bookmark` image resource & tag values a non-null `convertView` is passed in to `getView`.  Your `onClick` handler is setting them to these values:

```
bookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmarked);
bookmark.setTag(R.drawable.ic_bookmarked);
```

So you'll need to reset them to the default values when showing a new list item.

Comment: ok i sort of understand -- how and where do i reset the bookmark image resource?

Comment: Try resetting them after the call to `bookmark.setTag`

Comment: i tried in various areas of the code to set the orginal star icon. The best so far was to set it after -- bookmark.setTag(position);
        bookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark);  -- this seems  to stop duplicating the change of icon when cklicked but if i scroll down and up again the yellow star icon goes back to normal star icon.  any ideas please?

Comment: Yeah -- what you really should be doing is inside `getView` is check if the item is bookmarked and then set the image/tag appropriately...

Comment: my thoughts exactly, i tried putting an if statement in there,, quick question, does the tag remain to (setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmarked)) even after i set --  bookmark.setTag(position);
        bookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark);  -- because id didnt work -- ill try again, maybe i missed something

Comment: If you set a new tag, it'll overwrite the previous one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90371/discussion-between-buddy-and-tasos).

Comment: All done buddy. Yeah thanks for that flag idea. I set an extra item flag in the array to false and used (m) to set the flag to true when star is clicked. and finally an if statement in the getView to check the flag and set the icon accordingly. IM GLAD THIS OVER. :)))

Answer (score 1):

ListView reuses the views that fall out of range. You don't reset the "bookmark" icon when reusing the views (when you get a non-null `convertView`). Make sure to always reset all properties of your views to the correct values, and you won't have a problem.

Comment: do you know how i do that?

Comment: You have to set the same way as when you set the yellow star (`bookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmarked);`). But with another resource, of course.

Comment: thanks, i get  whats happening now, i just cant figure out where i need to set the original bookmark i con.